# MergeSort efficiency splice operation?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, mergesort

I have been studying MergeSort and read:

Recall that the slicing operator is O(k) where k is the size of the slice. In order to guarantee that mergeSort will be O(nlogn) we will need to remove the slice operator. Again, this is possible if we simply pass the starting and ending indices along with the list when we make the recursive call.

Every MergeSort I have seen/implemented myself has used the splice operator. How else can it be done? Am I overcomplicating this?

Comment: by splice you mean merge operation?

Comment: I think it means how the string is sliced. i.e. leftpart = alist[:mid]